# Making the NSStatusItem's button remain highlighted while NSPopover is on screen

Tags: cocoa, appkit

I have a `NSStatusItem` that displays a `NSPopOver` when its button (the new `button` property exposed in 10.10 which is a `NSStatusBarButton`) is clicked.

While the mouse is down, the button is highlighted blue, but it doesn't remain blue while the popover is visible. Does anyone know how to fix this so that the NSStatusItem behaves as if it was showing a menu instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up asking Developer Technical Support at Apple: looks like it's just not possible when using the new `NSStatusBarButton`.